# Cross-Origin Request Blocked while authenticating

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to design an OAuth2 authentication system that secures a variety of backend APIs.  I started by downloading and installing [the three interconnected Spring Boot / Cloud / OAuth2 apps in this github project](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2).

But my project requires two major architectural changes:

```
1.) The main portal UI must be running in Node.js, so that users can  
    view a public site and also login using a Node.js-hosted app that  
    makes REST calls to a backend authentication server, without feeling  
    like they are being redirected anywhere for authentication.   

2.) My app requires multi-factor authentication, so I need to create (or  
    at least customize) my own endpoints on the `authserver` app instead  
    of relying to the standard password authentication endpoint.
```

**What specific changes need to be made so that my Node.js-hosted UI app can successfully interact with the `authserver` app and the `resource` app?**

At the moment, adding AngularJS login code to either my own Node.js portal app OR to the `ui` app in the github sample results in the FireFox console showing the following error messages when the AngularJS code tries to call the `authserver` app running on `port 9000`:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading  
the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/login-form. (Reason: CORS  
header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading  
the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/login-form. (Reason: CORS  
request failed).
```

The AngularJS code that calls the new `/login-form` endpoint that I added to the `authserver` endpoint is:

```
$scope.credentials = {};

$scope.loginError = false;
$scope.showLogin = false;

$scope.loginShow = function() {
    $scope.showLogin = true;
    console.log('filler to add break point for debugger.');
};

$scope.loginLocal = function() {
    console.log('Just filler to add a break point in debugger.');
        var funcJSON = { 'type': 'Message',
                 'content1': $scope.credentials.username,
                 'content2': $scope.credentials.password
    };
        console.log('filler to add break point.');
    $http.post('http://localhost:9999/uaa/login-form', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.content1==='success'){
            $scope.Oauthenticated = true;
            console.log('filler to add a break point');
        }else {
            $scope.Oauthenticated = false;
            $scope.loginError = true;
            console.log('filler to add break point');
        }
    });
};
```

The FireFox debugger shows that the line of the above AngularJS code that throws the error in the FireFox console shown at top is:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:9999/uaa/login-form', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
```

I added a new `/login-form` end point to the `AuthserverApplication.java` file in the `authserver` app, and [you can read my entire new `AuthserverApplication.java` file at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/WS4UuImYFwBqLGA2C5zl).

I am open to running the main portal UI app inside of Spring Boot.  I have read that this would require using the @EnableSidecar annotation.  However, I get the same error message above whether the new login form is run inside the Spring Cloud `ui` app from the github link above, or from my Node.js-hosted portal UI.  **So what do I need to change to set up a secure way of managing this authentication from my Node.js-hosted portal app?**

---

**ONGOING RESEARCH:**

---

Per @Ulises' suggestion, I added code to override a method of `AuthserverApplication.java`.  I also double checked the url and slightly altered the url for the `$http.post(...` call (which I changed in-line above in the OP to avoid confusion.  The result is **the same error in the FireFox console**, plus an explicit log of the request in the Spring Boot log for the `authserver` app.

You can [read my new `AuthserverApplication.java` class including @Ulises's suggestion at a file sharing site by clicking this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/DQL8tUPCTbS430AJAE7H).  **The Node.js-hosted app that makes the call is running on `port 7000`.**

And you can [read the entire Spring Boot log for the request at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/8Elb5Fy4OTbhBHN97hAN).

---

Similarly, when I change the suggested method to read:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/login-form").allowedOrigins("http://localhost*");
}
```

I get [the Spring Boot error log that you can read at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/pwziRQ8g7aqRq6kJ1KSu).  And the Network tab of the FireFox debugger gives a 401 error, with the following raw headers:

Request headers:

```
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:7000
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 09:32:40 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache, no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="null", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

The same new error persists even when I add the following method to the `LoginConfig` inner class inside `AuthserverApplication.java` to try to get Spring Security to ignore the `/login-form` endpoint:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/login-form", "/error");
}
```

I am currently reading [the Spring OAuth2 Developer's Guide at this link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html), which refers to [sample apps on github at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2).  However, the sample apps use JSP, which is obsolete, and does not address the use case described in this OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AuthServerApplication` override method `addCorsMapping(CorsRegistry)` from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like this:

```
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/login-form").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
    }
```

Or wherever origin you're calling it from. You can also use `*` for everything and/or add any fine-grained configuration

Comment: This did not resolve the problem.  I will post an update in a few minutes.

Comment: I just added the results of trying your suggestion to the end of my OP, in an **ONGOING RESEARCH** section.  Any other ideas?